# How can I calculate distance (in meters) between two points on Google map

Tags: google-maps, gps, distance

I'm using an L80 GPS module together with my 8-bit processor. GPS module responds with a massage in NMEA format, giving me information about the date, time, latitude, longitude, altitude (if possible), number of satellites etc.

Latitude and longitude information of NMEA are in the form of degrees and minutes (DD°MM.mmm').
I'm able to convert them into only degrees notation (DD.dddddd°).

I have the following problem: Given a particular location (e.g. 48.858125, 2.294398) and a safety radius of, let's say, 50 meters (no more than 300 meters), how to determine weather (a, b) point is within a safety circle or not?
Can you help me figuring out the math hiding behind?

In short, I would like you to help me determine distance in meters between two points on Earth represented in angular coordinate system. Are there any math guru willing to help me? 
Note that my point of calculations is my processor.

I know that, having latitudes and longitudes in degrees, my points are represented in an angular coordinate system, not Cartesian (linear) one.I also know that Universal Transferse Mercator (UTM) representation of points on Earth is in Cartesian coordinate system. Is it, maybe, easier to transform degree notation (DD.dddddd°)  into UTM notation? I know there are on-line tools that are able to do a conversion. However, I don't know the math.

Thank you very much for your time and effort to help me.

Sincerely,

Bojan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the haversine formula to calcualte the distance between two points on earth.
Search for term "haversine" and the name of your programming language.

> Is it, maybe, easier to transform to UTM

No for sure not. It is very complex, and it gets extremly complex when the two points are located in different UTM zones.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply find distance b/w two points by longitude and latitude.

you can find reference code on [this](http://www.geodatasource.com/developers/javascript) link.

Hope this helps.